# Conditional statement in a function for PS1 are not re-evaluated

Tags: bash, prompt

I'm using a function to dynamically generate output for `PS1`. There are a couple statements that check if `node` and `package.json` exist, and if `git` and `.git` folder exist to display node version or the git branch. If none exist it just outputs the User$.

The problem is when user goes into another folder where none of the conditions are met the prompt is not updating. It's like conditions are cached or smth

```
function displayPS1() {
  MESSAGE="";
  GRAY_BACK="\[\e[100;97m\]";
  GREEN_BACK="\[\e[100;42m\]";
  GREEN_FORE="\[\e[32;1m\]";
  CYAN_BACK="\[\e[100;46m\]";
  CYAN_FORE="\[\e[36;1m\]";
  RESET="\[\e[0m\]";

  if hash node 2>/dev/null && [ -e package.json ]; then
    NODE='$(node -v | sed "s/\(v[0-9]*\)\(\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)/\1/g")';
    MESSAGE="${GRAY_BACK} node ${GREEN_BACK} $NODE ${RESET} User${GREEN_FORE}$ ${RESET}";
  elif hash git 2>/dev/null && [ -d .git ]; then
    BRANCH='$(cat .git/HEAD | sed "s/ref:[[:space:]]refs\/heads\///")';
    MESSAGE="${GRAY_BACK} git ${CYAN_BACK} $BRANCH ${RESET} User${CYAN_FORE}$ ${RESET}";
  else
    MESSAGE="User${CYAN_FORE}$ ${RESET}";
  fi

  echo "$MESSAGE";
}
export PS1=$(displayPS1);
```

Comment: You need to include the conditions in the PS1 (e.g. using `$(...)`).

Comment: Apart from anything else, `PS1` really does not need to be exported. It's just the shell using it.  Also, running `node` at least once, possibly twice for each prompt? Would it not be better to overload the `cd` command? The prompt would not need to be re-evaluated unless you change directory (most of the time at least).

Comment: I like the idea with the `cd`. But what if someone removes `package.json` or node or git, we would need to overload those commands also @Kusalananda

Comment: @Mr.Madamin Um? I'm not sure I follow how that's special if overloading `cd`? I was thinking something simple, like `cd () { builtin cd "$@"; PS1=$(displayPS1); }`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
export PS1=$(displayPS1);
```

This will run `displayPS1`, and the `if` statements within *once*, assigning the result to the prompt. The conditions won't be processed again after that.

Instead, put the function call in `PROMPT_COMMAND`, so it gets called every time the prompt is going to be printed. So either

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1=$(displayPS1)'
```

or perhaps rather

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=setPS1
```

and make `setPS1` a function that sets `PS1` itself. (Getting rid of the command substitution saves a fork from the subshell invocation every time the prompt is changed.)

Answer (score 5):

Use the quotes.

```
PS1='$(displayPS1)'
```

If you don't then the function is evaluated at assignment time.

Comment: It won't work, since it will escape the colors

Comment: @Mr.Madamin Is that not an issue with your `echo` at the end of the function (something that would be an issue regardless of when the function is evaluated)? Use `echo -e` instead of plain `echo`. You also seem to use single-quoted command substitutions in your code. Why?

Comment: @Kusalananda, no, because Bash handles backslash-escapes in the prompt. But it does so _before_ processing variable and command substitutions, so putting the function inside one breaks them. In particular, it breaks `\[ .. \]`, since you can't produce them with `echo -e` or such, they need to be in `PS1`.

Comment: @ilkkachu Fair enough. You're talking the the guy who uses `$` for prompt :-)

Comment: @Kusalananda, colors are optional, but I couldn't live without the working directory being included in the prompt...

Comment: What's wrong with `$` for prompt ? :) @ilkkachu

Comment: I used single quote inside in order to re-evaluate commands like node and git, and left colors separately. I found this solution on the web, as you can see, I'm a beginner in shell @Kusalananda